# Declaring a Fragment implementing an interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, extends

I want to declare something like this:

```
private <Fragment extends MyInterface> fragment;
```

because I want this fragment to be able to be set to a variety of different self-made Fragment objects that all implement MyInterface.

But it doesn't let me do this.

Is there a way to declare such a Fragment?

Comment: have you consider creating your own class, that extends Fragment and implements your interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
public interface MyFragmentInterface {
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyFragmentInterface {
}
```

Now to declare a variable:

```
private MyFragmentInterface fragment;
```

Comment: Yep, that worked (the last line in particular is what I needed)

Comment: The last line is the direct answer to the OP.